# How to convert a '\u5f71\u89c6\...' in to its real meaning?(python)

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

I want to convert

```
'[["[FK\u5f71\u89c6\u51fa\u54c1]\u7576\u65fa\u7238\u7238-17.\u7ca4\u8bed\u5b57\u5e55.TV-RMVB.rmvb", "205.53 MB"]]'
```

to

```
'[["[[FK影视出品]當旺爸爸-17.粤语字幕.TV-RMVB.rmvb", "205.53 MB"]]'
```

Because I make a mistake that I use `json.dumps(file_list)` convert a list object to str, and save the result to db.I find this mistabke until using sphinx to index these data...
I have tried use data.decode('utf-8'), but it seems not work.

Comment: Why not just decode again with `json.loads()`?

Comment: @Cyber: that's about as much use to the OP as a dirty Hungarian Phrasebook.

Comment: @Cyber mysql is utf8_general_ci,data should be utf-8 not ASCII.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters because I want my search engine can search chinese and janpanese, so data mustn't be something like '\u5f71' in database.

Comment: @@Martijn Pieters I use navicat to view the data, only `json.dumps(..)` colume not show in chinese and janpanese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decode from JSON again:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[["[FK\u5f71\u89c6\u51fa\u54c1]\u7576\u65fa\u7238\u7238-17.\u7ca4\u8bed\u5b57\u5e55.TV-RMVB.rmvb", "205.53 MB"]]')
[['[FK影视出品]當旺爸爸-17.粤语字幕.TV-RMVB.rmvb', '205.53 MB']]
```

You don't *have* UTF-8 encoded data, you have JSON-encoded data, which uses `\uhhhh` escape sequences to represent Unicode codepoints.

Comment: So,if I want to save something like `[FK影视出品]` which also need to be indexed.I should not use json.dump(), it that the point?

Comment: @Mithril: Depends; if you wanted to safe this data in a file between program invocations, using JSON might be a good idea, depending on your use cases. But then you also need to decode again when you are reading the data back.

Comment: @Mithril: but yes, you have a nested list here (doubly so), so `result[0][0]` is the contained string object.